# CASE in select statement MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I am having error in mysql query, so i need an if statement based on the previous select value.

here is my query,

```
SELECT
    ds.master_rcpt_gen,
    ds.visa_rcpt_gen,
    dsp.curr_amount,
    dsp.curr_id,
    mcr.conv_rate,
    mcr.curr_code,
    mcr.curr_desc,
    mcr.curr_type,
    (conv_rate / (select mcr.conv_rate from mst_currencies_rate mcr where mcr.curr_code = 'USD')) conv_ratio,
    curr_amount * (conv_rate / (select mcr.conv_rate from mst_currencies_rate mcr where mcr.curr_code = 'USD')) conv_usd,
    (select mtr.USD_tax_rate from mst_tax_rate mtr) * (curr_amount * (conv_rate / (select mcr.conv_rate from mst_currencies_rate mcr where mcr.curr_code = 'USD'))) AS conv_taxrate_commission,
    CASE WHEN mcr.curr_type = 'LOCAL' THEN conv_taxrate_commission = dsp.curr_amount ELSE (select mtr.USD_tax_rate from mst_tax_rate mtr) * (curr_amount * (conv_rate / (select mcr.conv_rate from mst_currencies_rate mcr where mcr.curr_code = 'USD')))
    END final_conv_rate 
FROM
    dtl_sr ds
INNER JOIN dtl_sr_payment dsp ON dsp.flight_id = ds.flight_id
AND dsp.sr_id = ds.SR_ID
INNER JOIN mst_currencies_rate mcr ON mcr.curr_id = dsp.curr_id
```

My error happened in case statement, i need the case statement to read value from conv_taxrate_commission. IF mcr.curr_type = 'LOCAL' i need conv_taxrate_commission to be equal to dsp.curr_amount, else i need to leave the conv_taxrate_commission as is.

Please help me

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: error 1054 unknown column 'conv_taxrate_commission' in 'field_list'

Comment: Why `conv_taxrate_commission = dsp.curr_amount` after `THEN` in `CASE` expression??

Comment: because if mcr.curr_type = 'LOCAL' then conv_taxrate_commission = dsp.curr_amount. if mcr.curr_type != 'LOCAL' then conv_taxrate_commission will equal the calculation for conv_taxrate_commission itself

Comment: @KonzMama I don't think you can do this in the sql. How about trying to add `case` `when` into your `(select mtr.USD_tax_rate from mst_tax_rate mtr) * (curr_amount * (conv_rate / (select mcr.conv_rate from mst_currencies_rate mcr where mcr.curr_code = 'USD'))) AS conv_taxrate_commission,` and when mcr.curr_type = 'LOCAL', what is  value of `final_conv_rate `.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I assume when mcr.curr_type = 'LOCAL', `final_conv_rate` is `dsp.curr_amount`;)

```
SELECT
  ds.master_rcpt_gen,
  ds.visa_rcpt_gen,
  dsp.curr_amount,
  dsp.curr_id,
  mcr.conv_rate,
  mcr.curr_code,
  mcr.curr_desc,
  mcr.curr_type,
  (conv_rate / (SELECT mcr.conv_rate
                FROM mst_currencies_rate mcr
                WHERE mcr.curr_code = 'USD'))                                                 conv_ratio,
  curr_amount * (conv_rate / (SELECT mcr.conv_rate
                              FROM mst_currencies_rate mcr
                              WHERE mcr.curr_code = 'USD'))                                   conv_usd,
  CASE WHEN mcr.curr_type = 'LOCAL'
    THEN dsp.curr_amount
  ELSE
    (SELECT mtr.USD_tax_rate
     FROM mst_tax_rate mtr) * (curr_amount * (conv_rate / (SELECT mcr.conv_rate
                                                           FROM mst_currencies_rate mcr
                                                           WHERE mcr.curr_code = 'USD'))) END conv_taxrate_commission,
  CASE WHEN mcr.curr_type = 'LOCAL'
    THEN dsp.curr_amount
  ELSE (SELECT mtr.USD_tax_rate
        FROM mst_tax_rate mtr) * (curr_amount * (conv_rate / (SELECT mcr.conv_rate
                                                              FROM mst_currencies_rate mcr
                                                              WHERE mcr.curr_code = 'USD')))
  END                                                                                         final_conv_rate
FROM
  dtl_sr ds
  INNER JOIN dtl_sr_payment dsp ON dsp.flight_id = ds.flight_id
                                   AND dsp.sr_id = ds.SR_ID
  INNER JOIN mst_currencies_rate mcr ON mcr.curr_id = dsp.curr_id
```